# Python merge two huge files by chunks

Tags: python, multithreading, merge, bigdata, generator

**Improved description and example after Vlad comment**
I have two files (A and B) and I need to merge them in a third file C, in this way:

- take some line from A and put in C
- take some line from B and put in C
- keep going on till all lines from A and B are in C.

I made an example to test the code and I created a list of tuples where the first element is a list of line numbers and the second element is a file which I want to read that lines from. I was thinking to perform the reading process with multiprocessing in order to speed up computation.

Here an example of the expected results:

**file_A.txt**

```
A0
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
A7
A8
A9
```

**file_B.txt**

```
B0
B1
B2
B3
B4
B5
B6
B7
B8
B9
```

Chunks are as follow:

```
lines [9] for file_B.txt
lines [4] for file_B.txt
lines [1] for file_A.txt
lines [4, 5, 7, 8] for file_A.txt
lines [3, 9] for file_A.txt
lines [6] for file_B.txt
lines [8] for file_B.txt
lines [0, 2, 3, 5] for file_B.txt
lines [0, 2, 6] for file_A.txt
lines [1, 7] for file_B.txt
```

**file_C.txt**

```
B9
B4
A1
A4
A5
A7
A8
A3
A9
B6
B8
B0
B2
B3
B5
A0
A2
A6
B1
B7
```

Here is an example of the code

```
from concurrent import futures
import os
from itertools import islice
from random import randint, shuffle
import time
import cProfile

def read(block):
    linenums = block[0]
    f = block[1]
    for i,line in enumerate(f):
        if i in linenums:
            yield line
    f.seek(0)


def random_chunk(li, min_chunk=1, max_chunk=3):
    it = iter(li)
    while True:
        nxt = sorted(list(islice(it,randint(min_chunk,max_chunk))))
        if nxt:
            yield nxt
        else:
            break

def random_partition(N,m=1,M=3):
    L = list(range(N))
    shuffle(L)
    M = randint(1,N)
    return list(random_chunk(L,m,M))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    if os.path.exists('file_C.txt'):
        os.remove('file_C.txt')

    N = 10
    with open('file_A.txt','w') as file_A:
        for i in range(N):
            file_A.write("A"+str(i)+"\n")

    with open('file_B.txt','w') as file_B:
        for i in range(N):
            file_B.write("B"+str(i)+"\n")
    print('files created')
    with open('file_A.txt') as file_A, open('file_B.txt') as file_B, open('file_C.txt','w') as file_C:
        partitions_A = random_partition(N)
        L_A = [(p, file_A) for p in partitions_A]
        partitions_B = random_partition(N)
        L_B = [(p, file_B) for p in partitions_B]
        L = L_A + L_B
        shuffle(L)
        for el in L:
            print(f"lines {el[0]} for {el[1].name}")

        print('shuffle')
        
        pr = cProfile.Profile()
        pr.enable()
        with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
            # schedule one map/worker for each block in the original data
            q = executor.map(read, [block for block in L])
            file_C.writelines([el for x in q for el in x])

        pr.disable()
        pr.print_stats(sort='tottime')
```

The problem is that with a high value of N (1000000) the code is taking a really lot of time on my laptop and in the real use case, I need to apply this code to files with millions of rows (up to 20GB per file).
I profiled for N=100000 and these are the results:

```
        202691 function calls (202669 primitive calls) in 90.688 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   200006   90.311    0.000   90.320    0.000 test.py:8(read)
        1    0.350    0.350   90.671   90.671 test.py:62(<listcomp>)
        1    0.010    0.010    0.010    0.010 {method 'writelines' of '_io._IOBase' objects}
      688    0.005    0.000    0.009    0.000 codecs.py:319(decode)
      688    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method _codecs.utf_8_decode}
        3    0.002    0.001    0.002    0.001 {built-in method marshal.loads}
       27    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}
```

Most of the time is taken from the reading part.

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the code? Is there a better strategy to face the problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're actually trying to achieve? It looks like you're trying to select random values from File_A and File_B and write them to File_C and for some reason that's unclear, you want to do this in chunks. Also, your output doesn't seem to align with the input. You have 20 values (10 each) in your input files but only 18 output values

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why do you think you need chunks? Why do you think you need multiprocessing?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The file A has in each line a json file coming from a stream of data; the file B some missing data of the same format. I want to have a unique file with all the data in the right order.  I already computed the right order and mapped it to lines numbers in the list I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I may be completely and totally wrong here, but you could maybe try the Python `linecache` module, described [here](https://pymotw.com/3/linecache/index.html). I don't know if, or how much it reads ahead, or what its policy is on cache ejection.

I did a quick experiment looking up a million random lines in `/usr/share/dict/words` on my Mac which has around 250,000 lines

```
import random
import linecache

In [18]: %%timeit
    ...:     for lookup in range(1000000):
    ...:         lineNumber = random.randint(1,250000)
    ...:         line = linecache.getline('/usr/share/dict/words', lineNumber)
    ...: 
608 ms ± 8.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I knew linecache and I already tried to use it but with a different code setup and I couldn't get good results. I just tried it within the code I posted and it seems great. With N=1e6 it took 2.4 second, while with N = 1e7 25sec. I will implement it in the real use case I have to use and let see. Thanks